# Phonegap 3.3 Build Android Failed

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build a project but when I type: `cordova build android` the following error occurred:

```
Generating config.xml from defaults
for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Compiling app on platform "android"
via command "../platforms/android/cordova/build"
Error: An error occurred
while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "../platforms/android/build.xml"":BUILD FAILED /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/ant/build.xml:932:The following error occurred
while executing this line: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.3/tools/ant/build.xml:950:null returned: 1

Total time: 18 seconds


at ChildProcess. < anonymous > (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit(events.js: 98: 17)
at maybeClose(child_process.js: 735: 16)
at Socket. < anonymous > (child_process.js: 948: 11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit(events.js: 95: 17)
at Pipe.close(net.js: 466: 12)
```

Is there a fix for this problem?

---

**EDIT**

I used brew to install Android-SDK and installed all possible build-tools:
[image: Android-SDK Location]

And my android manifest looks like:
[image: Android Manifest]

**EDIT2**

As requested here is the responce for `cordova build android --verbose`: http://pastebin.com/rqdkVKYG

Comment: have you installed ant and android sdk api19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the bug.

While testing, reinstalling android-sdk and ant. I tried to create a new project. Than typed in the terminal `cordova build` and it build flawlessly. After this I copied my existing WWW folder in to the new project. Typed `cordova build` again, it gave an error. Now I knew that the bug was in my WWW folder and not in the project itself. Scanning my folders I noticed a file with no extension(hidden files). I deleted the file and tried again. Success!

**SUMMARY:**
Scan your folders for files without extensions and delete or move them. Cordova doesn't like those.

---

**EDIT**

If this doesn't work try:

`cordova platform rm android`

then reinstall android using :

`cordova platform add android`

Now try to build.

Comment: Wow thanks, accidentally named a blank file ':' in vim, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: `cordova platform rm android` then `cordova platform add android` method works for me! thanks. Apparently I need to use `sudo cordova platform rm android` in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command `$home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/check_reqs` to check if you have all the required components installed for android.

Comment: Seems like I did it correctly:

`Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!`

Edit: Enter is Save :-/

Comment: Check the targetSdk version you have in androidManifest.xml and if you have installed the matching API in android sdk manager.

Comment: I checked and the targetSDK is 19. So I reinstalled the whole android-sdk using Homebrew to check if that was the problem. Still no luck. For reference I added img of my Android Manifest and my SDK location to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

¿Did you add to windows path the sdk?

You can also try:

- cordova platform add android
- cordova build

Comment: My PATH looks like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk:/usr/libexec/java_home` so my SDK is in the PATH

Answer (score 0):

try `ant -v` in your terminal and make sure it's above 1.8. Cordova requires that. 
Also check path is given correct for Ant, Android-SDK/tools, and Android-SDK/platformtools

To debug exact issue try `$Cordova build android --verbose`

Let me know.

Comment: When i do `ant -v` it gives this as result: `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed` so it is above 1.8. Here is the pastebin of `cordova build android --verbose`: http://pastebin.com/rqdkVKYG